# Event Delegation in jQuery 1.4

Tags: jquery, performance, hover, event-delegation

I've got the following code:

```
$("ul.relatedAlbums li").hover(function(){
    $(this).css({fontWeight:"bold"});
},
function(){
    $(this).css({fontWeight:"normal"});
});
```

I've heard good things about event delegation and speed performance. Using jQuery's delegate method, I imagine it would go something like:

```
$("ul.relatedAlbums").delegate("li", "hover", function(){
    $(this).css({fontWeight:"bold"});
},
function(){
    $(this).css({fontWeight:"normal"});
});
```

But reading the documentation, it says that this method is like using the live event. And I had always understood using the live event to be *inefficient*. So, could someone out there enlighten me on the best practices for this?

Comment: FYI The hover method is a convenience method that binds event handler to the mouseenter and mouseleave events but the performance difference should be minimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to point out, .delegate() actually uses .live() internally at present and to depricate .live() would mean some framework effort.

Unless you are adding elements to your page dynamically, you can use it as your first example.  .live() and .delegate come into play when you have an interactive page where you are making changes to the elements contained therein.

EDIT: to the downvoters:  From the jQuery forum:
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/depreciating-live
citing THIS code:

delegate: function( selector, types, data, fn ) {
        return this.live( types, data, fn, selector );
    },

My point being that a specific selector will limit the events if it is appropriate and just selecting .delegate() is not always best and there is no global "always do this".  Otherwise, why not just use .delegate() for everything which would not be best.

When WOULD delegate be appropriate?  When your selector DOES have a common parent such as the often used li as the OP describes or where binding to a common parent through the .delegate() is desireable.  Not for #selector in the singular, but worth examination for class or element selectors where multiples exist or dynamic placement of elements occurs.

Comment: not correct really. Why add x events to the dom when I can add just one. You do not need a dynamic page to gain a perf advantage by using event delegation.

Comment: @redsquare THIS was pulled from the 1.4.2 min source: delegate:function(a,b,d,f){return this.live(b,d,f,a)}

Comment: Added some notes to clarify what I ment.

Answer (score 1):

**The delegation concept**

If there are many elements inside one parent,and you want to handle events on them of them-don't bind handlers to each element.Instead,bind the signle handler to their parent,and get the child from event.target

**Then, what is JavaScript Event Delegation?**

Event delegation is a simple technique by which you attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all children matching a selector, whether those children exist now or are added in the future.

Event delegation makes use of two often overlooked features of JavaScript events: event bubbling and target element

**What is event bubbling?**

In event bubbling the event is first captured and handled by the inner most element and then propagated to outer elements

**What is target element?**

The target element of any event is the originating element,  and is stored in a property of the event object.

Example

```
<div id="container">
<ul id="list">
    <li><a href="http://domain1.com">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="/local/path/1">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/local/path/2">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://domain4.com">Item3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

When an anchor in our #list group is clicked, we want to log its text to the console. Normally we could directly bind to the click event of each anchor using the .on() method:

```
// attach a directly bound event
   $( "#list a" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log( $( this ).text() );
    });
```

While this works perfectly fine, there are drawbacks. Consider what happens when we add a new anchor after having already bound the above listener:

```
// add a new element on to our existing list
 $( "#list" ).append( "<li><a href='#'>Item 5</a></li>" )
```

If we were to click our newly added item, nothing would happen. This is because of the directly bound event handler that we attached previously. Direct events are only attached to elements at the time the .on() method is called. In this case, since our new anchor did not exist when .on() was called, it does not get the event handler.

Since we know how events bubble, we can create a delegated event:

```
// attach a delegated event
$( "#list" ).on( "click", "a", function( event ) {
event.preventDefault();
console.log( $( this ).text() );
});
```

Notice how we have moved the a part from the selector to the second parameter position of the .on() method. This second, selector parameter tells the handler to listen for the specified event, and when it hears it, check to see if the triggering element for that event matches the second parameter. In this case, the triggering event is our anchor tag, which matches that parameter. Since it matches, our anonymous function will execute. We have now attached a single click event listener to our  that will listen for clicks on its children anchors, instead of attaching an unknown number of directly bound events to the existing anchor tags only.

**What are the Advantages of Event Delegation?**

Only attach one event listener to the page, rather than five hundred
Dynamically created elements will still be bound to the event handler.

Hopefully this helps you visually the concept behind event delegation and convinces you of delegation's power!
visit:http://www.scriptcafe.in/2014/03/what-is-event-delegation-in-jquery.html

Answer (score 0):

Event delegation allows you to not bind events to individual elements, but to the element's common parents.

However .live() is inefficient in the sense that when the event is bubbling, it is bubbling to document, which is likely many steps away from a common parent you can manually specify.

Delegate fixes that by allowing you a specify a closer parent, not necessarily the document.

In short, use .delegate(), it's got everything that's good about .live() and fixes the problematic aspect.

To put it another way: .live() by default bubbles to the document. You can specify a closer context, and that'll eliminate its inefficiencies. .delegate() is just the sugar method that helps you do that.

Comment: To be clear, you're saying that of the two examples above, "delegate" is *BETTER* than binding the hover event to each specific li? I don't need the live aspect.

Comment: Delegate is better if you have multiple li per ul. If you bind on li, you bind multiple times. If you use delegate, you bind once on the parent. That's why it's better.